# Storing multiple artist name for a song in database

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am creating a database to store information of songs. One of the issues that I am facing is that a song can have multiple artists. What is the best way to store such data?

I am trying to take care of a situation in which what if there are 30 artists for a song and there are 100s of such songs. In that case if I 2 tables, one for songs and other of artists with song_id as foreign key.

I am trying to tackle this situation

Answer (score 1):

This is a many-to-many relationship so you need to create an artist_song intersection table that holds foreign keys to the artist table and the song table

Comment: So there is absolutely no other way to store  this data other than creating a separate table for it

Comment: There probably are other ways of storing the data - as long as you don’t mind breaking all the standard rules of good database design

Comment: Can you please tell me what ways are there, both if I want to break standard rules of good design and when I dont want to

Comment: Sorry, i’m not going to tell you how to badly design your database. You need to read up on data normalisation, especially the 3rd normal form 3NF